# {"The directory name is invalid"} Win32Exception Was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, windows, backup

I am trying to backup the database using mysql and c#
by using following way...

```
  public static  void backupDatabase()
    {
        Process sd = null;
        ProcessStartInfo r1 = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\\", "--databases=access --compress --routines --triggers --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --add-locks --extended-insert --port=3080 --user=root --disable-keys --quick --comments --complete-insert --result-file=DUMPEDOUTPUT.sql");

        r1.CreateNoWindow = true;
        r1.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\\";
        r1.UseShellExecute = false;
        r1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        r1.RedirectStandardInput = false;

        sd = Process.Start(r1);
         sd.WaitForExit();

        if (!sd.HasExited)
        {
             sd.Close();
        }
        sd.Dispose();
         r1 = null;
         sd = null;  

    }
```

got an exception at this line    `sd = Process.Start(r1);`

```
Exception :{"The directory name is invalid"}   Win32Exception Was unhandled
```

would any one pls help me guys

Many thanks In advance..

**Modified Code :**

```
  public static  void backupDatabase()
    {
        Process sd = null;
        ProcessStartInfo r1 = new ProcessStartInfo("MySQLWorkbench.exe", "--databases access --compress --routines --triggers --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --add-locks --extended-insert --port=3080 --user=root --disable-keys --quick --comments --complete-insert --result-file=DUMPEDOUTPUT.sql");

        r1.CreateNoWindow = true;
        r1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe";
        r1.UseShellExecute = false;
        r1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        r1.RedirectStandardInput = false;

        sd = Process.Start(r1);
         sd.WaitForExit();

        if (!sd.HasExited)
        {
             sd.Close();
        }
        sd.Dispose();
         r1 = null;
         sd = null;  

    }
```

I am getting same error at the same line ..

Comment: I can't see an executable file name in `ProcessStartInfo`...is that the case?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on that line, verify the same value can be used from the command line. You need to at least attempt to resolve this on your own. You need to use what was actually suggested in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686256/how-to-backup-the-database-using-mysql-and-c-net

Comment: Bit disapointed you've opened a new question rather than followed up with the answer on the original question you opened.  I did provide hints in the code I provided where you needed to enter the path to your own copy of mysqldump.exe - in this modified version above you've only entered the path to MySQL Workbench, which is not the backup tool you need to target.  You still need to have MySQL installed on the machine you want to run this code.

Comment: @simbolo i have found mysql.exe in this path  so i have entered this patrh but still i am getting the same error           r1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\mysql.exe";

Comment: Try by providing the working directory only till the containing folder: r1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE";

Comment: @JayantaDey still i am getting same error ...  r1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE i ahve tried this..

Comment: You haven't set a full path to the executable (new ProcessStartInfo("MySQLWorkbench.exe"...), you set a FULL path to the exe, then for working directory, only the containing folder (not including the exe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe.aspx) should be the executable you want to run.  Right now you have it pointing to a directory

```
new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\\", ...
```

It should probably be

```
new ProcessStartInfo(
   @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe", ...
```

You can also specifiy the path name by using `@` in front of the string so you dont need to escape the backslashes.  Like this:

```
new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\", ...
```

**Update 1**

Another thing to try, since you already specify the working directory, just put the executable name in the `ProcessStartInfo`

```
new ProcessStartInfo("MySQLWorkbench.exe", ...
```

**Update 2**

Just noticed you added the exe filename to the `WorkingDirectory`.  This should just be the directory:

```
Process sd = null;
ProcessStartInfo r1 = new ProcessStartInfo("MySQLWorkbench.exe", ...);

r1.CreateNoWindow = true;
r1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE";
```

But I think the issue is probably the permissions.  My guess is the current user doesnt have permissions to this file path.

Comment: Your two examples are exactly the same.  This really doesn't answer his question, although I would admit, its an extremely poor question and shows zero effort on his part to figure it out on his own.

Comment: @Ramhound - I was showing the use of the `@` symbol.  I've added what I think should resolve the OP's problem.

Comment: This does answer his question. The first parameter of `ProcessStartInfo` needs to be a launchable file, as outlined in his example. His second example is outling his use of the `@` symbol.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 i have changed what you suggested but i am still getting same error....

Comment: @SwDevMan81  would you pls see my modified code .. I have did what you have suggested  but i am getting the same error at the same line

Comment: At this point I think its probably a permissions issue.  You probably dont have access to the directory.  Make sure the current user can access it.